# Configuring Yocto U-Boot for Beagleboard based setup

Tags: linux, yocto, u-boot

So we've made a board based on Omap3-beagleboard but with 2 differences, a 256MB DRAM (  instead of 128 ), and a 1Gb NAND.
I have managed to use *Yocto* to build a Linux system for *Beagleboard* now and deployed the image to SD card, however I think because of the difference in size of DRAM the *U-Boot* process is stuck.
So I have two questions:

1. Is the outcome really because of the different DRAM size?
2. And If it is, how can I alter U-Boot to assume DRAM size to be 256MB?

Console Output:

```
OMAP3 Beagle board + LPDDR/NAND
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  128 MiB
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0
Loading Environment from NAND... *** Warning - readenv() failed, using default environment

Beagle Rev Ax/Bx
Recognized KBADC Beagle FPGA board
No EEPROM on expansion board
No EEPROM on expansion board
OMAP die ID: 5268000700000000015a85e60c01c014
Net:   usb_ether
Error: usb_ether address not set.

starting USB...
USB0:   USB EHCI 1.00
scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for ethernet devices... 0 Ethernet Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
```

Comment: *Is the outcome really because of the different DRAM size?*" -- Probably, although you only provided an ambiguous description of "*outcome*".  Your SBC is not like an x86 PC, which has a BIOS to auto-detect the amount of installed RAM.  Instead, the typical embedded system has boot programs with hardcoded memory parameters.  You need to modify all of your boot programs to match all of your DRAM changes, especially  initialization of the DRAM controller.  BTW U-Boot has a memory test command.  Seems like you need to do some basic HW testing.

Answer (score -1):

Memory timing can be found in the file board/ti/beagle/beagle.c in the u-boot code source. You will have to add your own, there are actually several memories available. Check the get_board_mem_timings function :-)

Comment: Answers are supposed to definitively answer the question, not to invite further questions.  If you have questions they belong in the comment section

Comment: Sorry first time I publish on stackoverflow, will fix now - EDIT I can't I need to have a huge reputation :-(

Comment: Yes, the system is designed such that you should generate enough reputation before you start contributing in this way.

Comment: There is no reputation requirement for editing your own post. You just need to [edit]. If you refer to commenting (only 50 reputation required, not "huge"...), then...

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.